# Interaction with programatically created UISearchController blocked iOS 9

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uisearchcontroller

Here is the `UISearchController` I made.

```
var resultSearchController = UISearchController()
var myTableView = UITableView()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    myTableView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 21, view.bounds.width, view.bounds.height-20) //programatically made my tableview for use with UISearchController
    myTableView.delegate = self
    myTableView.dataSource = self

    myTableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")

    self.resultSearchController = ({
        let controller = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
        controller.searchResultsUpdater = self
        controller.searchBar.delegate = self
        controller.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
        controller.searchBar.sizeToFit()
        controller.searchBar.userInteractionEnabled = true
        controller.searchBar.hidden = false

        self.myTableView.tableHeaderView = controller.searchBar // attach searchBar to tableView

        return controller
    })()

    UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow?.addSubview(myTableView) //put view on top of navigation bar
```

Similar questions suggest that the parent view is not big enough. I don't think that is an issue here. Also it was suggested that the `SearchController` is covered by another view. Again, I don't see that as the problem.

I can interact with my `tableView` just fine. When I tap the `SearchBar`, nothing happens. What is going on?

Here is my app.

[image: My app]

EDIT: Here is my app after the posted answer:

[image: app bug]

Comment: In UI View Hierarchy,nothing blocks the UISearchBar

Comment: How do I find that out?

Comment: I got `UITextField` from searchBar,and call `becomeFirstResponder` on it,nothing happens too.

Comment: I am having trouble understanding, what are you telling me?

Comment: textField.canBecomeFirstResponder() return false,which indicates that it can't gain focus on UIWindow's subview I guess.

Comment: You are correct. If I add the view as a subview to my `UIView`, tapping the searchBar works. But I want the view with the searchBar to be on top of my main view's nav bar, hence adding the searchBar view as a subview to UIWindow. What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out a solution which might help you.

Replace this:

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow?.addSubview(myTableView)
```

With this:

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow?.subviews.last?.addSubview(myTableView)
```

Comment: Thanks! This works, but with one minor bug: When I select the searchBar, it scrolls up and is behind the status bar. How should I fix this?

Comment: Did you programmatically set the searbar's frame?

Comment: I used `controller.searchBar.sizeToFit()` as seen in my question.

Comment: I just copied your code into my project,and everything works fine.

Comment: Except for one thing, I just put the solution code into viewDidAppear method.You can give it a try.

Comment: I put `UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow?.subviews.last?.addSubview(myTableView)` in viewDidAppear, and I have the same issue.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88221/discussion-between-benson-tommy-and-user3711622).

Comment: Why does your solution work? What does it do that my code didn't?